# Pagination links in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I created pagination in codeigniter, but the links on the pagination link is wrong.
its looks like
1="", 2="1", 3="4"

What is the best way to fix links on pagination indexes?
There is total 5 entries in the table and i need to show 2 entries per page (for example)

controller

```
$this->load->model("candidate_model");
            $this->load->model("client_model");
            //$data["candidate"] = $this->candidate_model->fetch_candidate();
            $this->load->library('pagination');
            $config['base_url']="http://localhost/hol/auth/client_enter";
            $config['per_page']     = 2;
            $config['total_rows']  = 5;
            $config['uri_segment'] = 3; //see from base_url. 3 for this case

            $config['prev_link'] = '&lt;';
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $data["candidate"]      = $this->client_model->fetch_candidate();


            $data["designation"] =     $this->candidate_model->fetch_designation();
            $this->load->view('client_home', $data);
```

model

```
function fetch_candidate()
        {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT U.user_id, U.firstname, U.lastname,U.username,U.usertype,U.email,U.phone,U.address, U.profile_image, C.name AS
     country,C.id AS countryid, S.name as state,S.id as stateid, A.housename,A.street,A.area,A.po,A.city, CJ.designation,
      CJ.resume, CJ.biography, CJ.hiring_mode, CJ.notice_period, CJ.current_CTC, CJ.expected_CTC, D.designation_id as 
      desig, D.designation as desig_name from users as U LEFT JOIN address as A on U.user_id=A.cand_id LEFT JOIN 
      cand_job_details AS CJ on CJ.cand_id=U.user_id LEFT JOIN designations as D on D.designation_id=CJ.designation LEFT 
      JOIN countries AS C on C.id=A.country LEFT JOIN states as S on S.id=A.state where usertype='1' && U.status='1' limit 1,2");
            return $query;
        }
```

view

```
<?php  echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

Comment: According to the manual you are on the right track. I would double check that your fetch_candidate is pulling through the right data - `LIMIT 1,2` is hardcoded and you may want it variable.

Comment: Thank you, it works

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, I think the link on each pages should be set as the offset when selecting data from the DB